# How do I make background code?

Tags: c#

I want to make background code that checks if someone hit "H","D", or other letters. Like This,(I mean a background code that is checking this.)

```
if(e.KeyCode == Keys.U)
{
code;
}
```

Comment: If you want it on background as in a keylogger, have a look at this: http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/create-simple-hidden-console-keylogger-c-sharp-0132757/.

Answer (score 1):

In WinForms you can override onKeyDown() like so:

```
protected override void onKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.YourKey)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Where you substitute YourKey with desired key from Keyboard. (You can use intellisense to see all available options)

Comment: I guess this wont work for background!